# Laravel Scrape Problem [Slow Execute Time]

Tags: laravel

I have a web scrape data problem using laravel and the use of laravel is slow in using CURL.

I want to ask if I can run a normal PHP script without using Laravel framework and pass a php variable into the Laravel controller?

Thank you for participating to answer this question.

Comment: Quick and broad answer is yes. And you can also run your script and dump data to a file, then process within Laravel, or whatever you want to do. In case you require details, feel free to post a piece of the slow running code and some scenario background to let other peers diagnose better.

Comment: ofcourse you can.. you can run a script then make an API to pass to laravel controller

Comment: how ? do you have some example ? where i can put the php ? and how i passing to controller ? i'am not sure using api becase it make work double and hassle.